# Can a Bluetooth device be detected by its unique address from Windows C++ application?

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth, esp32

I have to write an application which has to identify "ESP32" devices & send/receive data from a Windows C++ application.

Q1: I am using `WSALookupServiceBegin()` API to find the BT device, it was not working as expected. API returns 10108 until I manually click on "Add devices" in Windows Bluetooth window. Is there any other API/service which can discover BT near devices or am I using the `WSALookupServiceBegin()` API wrongly?
Is `WSALookupServiceBegin()` takes the device data from the Bluetooth cache? I got this doubt because API works fine only after manual search in Windows.

Q2: is it possible to connect to any Bluetooth device just with the Mac ID of BT device from Windows?

Please find the code below.

```
WSAQUERYSET data;
HANDLE handle;
ZeroMemory(&data, sizeof(data));
data.dwSize = sizeof(data);
data.dwNameSpace = NS_BTH;
data.lpcsaBuffer = NULL;

WSALookupServiceBegin(&data, LUP_CONTAINERS, &handle);
while(WSALookupServiceNext(hLookup, LUP_RETURN_NAME | LUP_RETURN_ADDR, 
&dwSize, pwsaResults)
{
 service_classID = pwsaResults->lpServiceClassId;
 _BTH_DEVICE_INFO *dev = (_BTH_DEVICE_INFO *)pwsaResults->lpBlob->pBlobData;

    SOCKET          LocalSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKADDR_BTH    SockAddrBthServer;

    SockAddrBthServer.btAddr = dev->address;
    SockAddrBthServer.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    SockAddrBthServer.serviceClassId = *service_classID;
    SockAddrBthServer.port = 0;

    // connect to socket
    LocalSocket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == LocalSocket) {
        wprintf(L"socket() call failed. WSAGetLastError = [%d]\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    if (SOCKET_ERROR == connect(LocalSocket,
        (struct sockaddr *) &SockAddrBthServer,
        sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH))) {
        wprintf(L"connect() call failed. WSAGetLastError=[%d]\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT :

connect() call failed. WSAGetLastError=[10049]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WSALookupServiceBegin` is correct way but you have to provide correct flags for it. Also you can use `BluetoothFidnFirstDevice` and `BluetoothFindNextDevice` functions from Bluetooth API.

However both methods always return paired devices even they are not available (together with just found devices).

From your description it looks you did not provide correct flags for `WSAxxx` function.

If you know device's MAC and it has not been changed then you can connect to device by MAC without rediscovering it each time. Depending on your device's authentication requirement you even do not need to pair with device (of course if your device does not need authentication and/or encryption).

Comment: Thanks for the response. i have updated my code. can you please have a look at it.

Comment: WSALookupServiceBegin must be called with (LUP_CONTAINERS | LUP_RETURN_ADDR | LUP_FLUSHCACHE) (the same flags must be used in WSALookupServiceNext(). Do not use LUP_RETURN_NAME because it does nothing if device just found. You have to query device's name after discovering or handle WM_DEVICECHANGE message that sent when device's name has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the flags & now it is working fine, not taking the data from cache. How do i query the device name from the "pwsaResults" after running WSALookupServiceNext().

Comment: I got the name of the device by using LUP_RETURN_BLOB | LUP_RETURN_NAME.

Comment: Next one is connect to the device, How can i proceed with the remote address or name of the device and how?

Comment: i got the details into "_BTH_DEVICE_INFO", which mean i have address & name & classID etc. How can i connect to BT device using the remote address?

Comment: Sorry but you are asking for ready solution or for starting point? [This is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bluetooth/bluetooth-programming-with-windows-sockets) good start point.

Comment: i used connect() API to connect to Bluetooth device, i am getting 10049 error. I have updated my code. can you please have a look?

Comment: pwsaResults->lpServiceClassId - probably empty because you discovering devices, not services. Provide correct service's UUID that is supported by your device. Make sure address is valid. Also port must be BTPORT_ANY.